# Halogen bulb goes on and off when a dimmer switch is activated

Tags: halogen

I have just fitted a halogen wall lamp in a hallway running from 2 switch points, one by the front door and one in the kitchen. Both switches are dimmers, the type that you depress and hold down to dim the bulb. When you turn either dimmer switch on the halogen bulb goes on and off continuously whilst you are holding the dimmer switch on. When you release/depress the dimmer switch the bulb stays off. I have also tried the lamp with a dimmer halogen and the same thing happens. Before I replace the dimmer switches altogether with standard on/off switches is there anything else I can try? Is there anyone who can explain what is happening? Please!

Comment: What voltage is the halogen fixture?  If it's 12 or 24 you need a dimmer for low voltage fixtures.

Comment: What model are these dimmers?